# MDI Windows with multiple MDIChields in different WindowState

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have a little problem with my MDI Parent Window and the MDI Childs window. The problem is that i need 3 child window but only the first it'll be maximize, so i use this code:

```
UserAdmin usrWindow = new UserAdmin();
usrWindow.MdiParent = this;
usrWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
usrWindow.Show();
```

For the others 2 windows i use this code:

```
TaskAdmin tskWindow = new TaskAdmin ();
tskWindow.MdiParent = this;
tskWindow.Show();
```

I only need that the first windows is maximized, but when i open the others they open maximized too.

How can i do to open one maximized and others in the default size over the first?

Thanks

Comment: You desired behavior is not available by design of .NET WF BC. You can implement your own version of MDI using Win32, or using native C/C++

Comment: fcartu, what do you want to achieve by having an MDI container with some forms maximized and others non maximized? Knowing what you want to achiveve can help us to provide alternatives of doing your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, yet can be achieved with very very tricky (using WndProc override, custom event loops) and ugly code which will not work in different operation systems in the same manner (i.e WinXP/WinXPSP1/WinXPSP3/Vista/Win7)

Answer (score 0):

Your TaskAdmin forms cannot have an MDIParent in this situation.  You need to either float these forms over the MDIParent or place them in panels in the MDIParent, docked to a side.